# Strange webview goBack issue in android

Tags: android, android-webview

I am using webview in Android. But strangely, sometimes even webview `canGoBack` method returns `true`, webview `goBack` method doesn't work.

```
if (webView.canGoBack()) 
    webView.goBack();
```

Thanks for any idea.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I finally managed to figure out how to do it

```
@override
public void onFormResubmission(WebView view, Message dontResend, Message resend)
{
  resend.sendToTarget();
}
```

default behaviour of onFormResubmission is not to resubmit. resend.sendToTarget() changes that.

this will make your hardware back button work if you have made some code to handle the hardware button

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
  if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
    mWebView.goBack();
    return true;
  }
  return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: I am using the above code and having issue of method mWebView.canGoBack() always returns true even if there is no history. The problem is I can not go back to previous activity when pressing device back button because mWebView.canGoBack() returns true. Any help?

Comment: this fixed the issue i was having.

Answer (score 4):

I have disabled the cache and then it worked:

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
```

Answer (score -2):

use this one windows.history.back();