# Webview does NOT finish loading

Tags: android, android-webview

If I use a button it works, but it redirects to a default browser. 
I want to use the webview because i want to display the website in my webview and avoid the address bar to display.

Here is my code:

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);

    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://178.239.16.28/fzs/sites/default/files/dokumenti-vijesti/sample.pdf");
    webview.setWebViewClient (new WebViewClient());
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code sequence and let me know if any issues. Don't forget to add permission to your AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Change to below :

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webview.setWebViewClient (new HelloWebViewClient());
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://178.239.16.28/fzs/sites/default/files/dokumenti-vijesti/sample.pdf");
```

And use below snippts

```
private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {


        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your url is redirecting.

You'll have to override [shouldOverrideUrlLoading](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#shouldOverrideUrlLoading%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29)

> Give the host application a chance to handle the key event synchronously. e.g. menu shortcut key events need to be filtered this
>   way. If return true, WebView will not handle the key event. If return
>   false, WebView will always handle the key event, so none of the super
>   in the view chain will see the key event. The default behavior returns
>   false.
>
> **Parameters**
>
> *view*    The WebView that is initiating the callback.
>
> *event*   The
>   key event.
>
> **Returns** True if the host application wants to handle the
>   key event itself, otherwise return false

Answer (score 0):

Use this lines ..

```
package org.example.webviewdemo;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;


public class WebViewDemo extends Activity {


    private WebView webView;


    Activity activity ;
    private ProgressDialog progDailog; 

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        activity = this;

        progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "Loading","Please wait...", true);
        progDailog.setCancelable(false);



       webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_compontent);



       webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);     
       webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
       webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);        
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                progDailog.show();
                view.loadUrl(url);

                return true;                
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
                progDailog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        webView.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://178.239.16.28/fzs/sites/default/files/dokumenti-vijesti/sample.pdf");

    }


}
```

It will show loader until loading the file. then loader get hide once file have loaded using google docs. hope this will help you.